# Run a separate task in background django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've to perform two tasks in an API request but I want to run the second task asynchronously in the background so the API doesn't have to wait for the second task and return the response after the completion of the first task, so how can I achieve it?

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_project(request):
   data = first_task()
   second_task(data) # want to run this function at background
   return Response("Created") # want to return this response after completion of first_task()
```

Comment: Take look at Django Celery 
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use other methods to run async function, you can use any of the following:

- [django-background-tasks](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks): Simple and doesn't require a worker
- [python-rq](http://python-rq.org/patterns/django/): Great for simple async tasks
- [celery](https://www.celeryproject.org): A more complete solution

Comment: Or you can start a new thread for this particular tasks, and manage well to close the thread, different scenarios.

Comment: @RanuVijay I did the same.. I've created a new thread but unfortunately, the API is waiting for the completion of the new thread..

Comment: @ahmed, can you please share any appropriate and simple examples?

Comment: @ZainKhan stackoverflow has a lot of question try exploring.

Comment: achieved it using threading.. thank for your help